# Gitlab on Kubernetes: Runner registration problem when doing a new Helm Release

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner

TLDR : With Gitlab self-hosted on Kubernetes , installed with Helm charts, we are having an issue related to Gitlab Runner registration when doing new successive Helm chart deployments after the first one where everything was working.

Context :

We are running Gitlab as self-hosted on Kubernetes (GKE) on Google Cloud using the [official Helm chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/). The Helm chart is installed through Terraform with the [helm_release](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release) Terraform ressource of the Helm provider by Hashicorp. The Gitlab Runner is enabled on the official Global Helm chart of Gitlab (we are not using a separate chart or the Operator). We are using an external DB (Cloud SQL), external Redis (MemoryStore) and external object storage (Cloud Storage).

*Example of our helm_release in Terraform:*

```yaml
resource "helm_release" "gitlab" {
  name             = "gitlab"
  description      = "gitlab install"
  repository       = "https://charts.gitlab.io/"
  chart            = "gitlab"
  version          = "7.1.2"
  create_namespace = false
  namespace        = "gitlab"
  atomic           = true
  max_history      = 5
  timeout          = 900
 
  values = [
    templatefile("${path.module}/../gitlab/gitlab-helm-values.yaml", {
      GITLAB_ROOT_DOMAIN    = var.gitlab_root_domain,
      GITLAB_URL            = var.gitlab_url,
      PSQL_HOST             = google_sql_database_instance.gitlab.private_ip_address,
      PSQL_DB               = google_sql_database.gitlab.name,
      PSQL_USER             = google_sql_user.gitlab_user.name,
      REDIS_HOST            = google_redis_instance.cache.host,
      ...
    }),
  ]
 
  depends_on = [
    google_container_cluster.gitlab,
    google_container_node_pool.gitlab,
    ...
  ]
}
```

We are having an issue related to Gitlab Runner registration:  when doing a new release of Gitlab (not necessarily with a version upgrade, could be the same configuration but with a different release name), the new Gitlab Runner pod just won’t register itself (the pod stay in error). In addition, when trying to access the runners page from the Admin area, I get an Error 500 Internal Error page.

[image: runner pod error message]

Others pods are working fine (for the exception of the database migration job, more details later) and I can access the web interface and get my data back (config, repos...) because the new deployment is still pointing to the same stateful parts (Cloud SQL, Memorystore, same persistent disk with previous data...). However, the Runner is not registering / working.

Everything is ok when we do a fresh install from scratch on a new cluster. Also, doing a new release with the old release name that was working also seems to fix the problem (however, I can see the old runners registered as still online but they will not be used).

**My suspicion is that there is a problem with persistent (stateful) data between Helm releases that creates conflict**. Basically, doing a new Helm release (with a different name) delete the old pods and such, but let others objects like Secrets and ConfigMaps in place (documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/installation/uninstall.html)). New Secrets with a new release name will be created but the old one stay in place.

In addition to the Runner registration problem, we have the migration job that is failing (he starts back at number 1) when doing a new release (same version and configuration, just a new release name).

[image: database migration job failing]

I know that changing the release name creates a new install with Helm (and not an upgrade) but I would like to understand why it’s failing, what are the dependencies.

Thank you!